# Why would electrons have Weak Charge?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

Electrons (and, their cousins Muon and Tau) carry Weak Charge having value $-1/2$.

**If you believe in *Strong Anthrophic Principle***
Why does electrons carry Weak Charge?

**If you don't believe in *Strong Anthrophic Principle***
Does electrons participate in Weak Force interactions naturally? Is there a mechanism known with which electrons get Weak Charge?

Comment: Electrons are involved in the beta decay of nuclei.

Comment: Whether electrons participate in weak force interactions doesn't depend on one believing in something, so the second question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ruslan I meant to say that If you don't believe in Strong Anthrophic Principle, answer this..

Comment: To ask *why* something has a certain charge is pointless - if it had a different charge, it would be a different object. And it is a matter of fact that the electron participates in weak interaction, hence we conclude it carries a weak charge.

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1. It's not pointless. See Strong Anthrophic Principle. Not all believe it however. 2. I added *naturally* to second question..

Comment: A slight change in that value can disrupt our existence..

Comment: _Is there a mechanism known with which electrons get Weak Charge?_ As far as I know, electrons can't get weak charge, they simply have it. Like they have electric charge.

Comment: @jinawee You are wrong as per QFT and M-Theory.

Comment: I don't see that the anthropic principle applies to this question at all unless you truly mean "why" in some sort of philosophical sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few different things which you might refer to as "weak charge," and I'm not sure which you've chosen here.  The electron and the other charged leptons are members of [weak isospin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_isospin) [doublets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_state); they must have total weak isospin $\frac12$ to be able to rotate into their corresponding neutrinos, an interaction mediated by the $W^\pm$ boson.

Wikipedia thinks "weak charge" is [weak hypercharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_hypercharge), which is $-1$ for left-handed leptons (charged and neutrino both) and $+1$ for left-handed baryons; the hypercharges for the right-handed particles are different to account for the fact that a right-handed neutrino would have zero weak hypercharge and not participate in charged-current weak interactions.

I have a [professional bias](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.5275) for considering the "weak charge" as something analogous to the electric charge: a parameter intrinsic to a particle which determines its coupling to the [weak neutral current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_neutral_current). In this scheme the electroweak charges are
$$
\begin{array}{ccll}
\text{particle} & \text{electric charge} & \text{weak charge} \\
e & -1 & -1 + 4 s_W^2 &\approx -0.041 \\
\nu & 0 & +1 \\
u & +\tfrac23 & +1-\tfrac83 s_W^2 &\approx +\tfrac13 \\
d & -\tfrac13 & -1 +\tfrac43 s_W^2 &\approx -\tfrac23 \\
\text{proton}=uud & +1 & +1-4s_W^2 &\approx -0.041 \\
\text{neutron}=udd & 0 & -1
\end{array}
$$
Here $s_W^2 = \sin^2\theta_W \approx \frac14$ is related to the [weak mixing angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_mixing_angle), a fundamental parameter of the standard model whose value [depends on momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group).  Note that for the electron and proton the weak charge is *almost* zero; in fact the difference between the low-momentum $\sin^2\theta_W = 0.2397$ and the high-momentum ("$Z$-pole") $\sin^2\theta_W = 0.23120$ changes the weak charge for $e$ and $p$ by about a factor of two.

These charges arise from the coupling terms in the Standard Model Lagrangian.

Comment: Still not sure if I did the right thing when I chose a Double Chooz postdoc over a Qweak one, but congrats.

Comment: Double Chooz was a fine experiment, too. We should have a beer sometime.

Comment: An [updated version of this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/405540/44126) on another question.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Jerry Schirmer, electrons are involved in the beta decay of nuclei. This reaction goes as follows:

$$ n \rightarrow p + e^- + \bar{\nu}_e $$

The modern theory of (electro)weak interactions treats them as Yang-Mills interactions based on the $SU(2)\times U(1)$ gauge group. In the reaction above a new intermediate force carrier, the $SU(2)$ gauge boson (specifically, $W^-$) is introduced:

$$ n \rightarrow p + W^- \rightarrow p + e^- + \bar{\nu}_e $$

In order to couple neutrinos and electrons to the weak bosons, we must specify their weak charge. The structure of the gauge theory explains it naturally.

It is also worth mentioning that only left-handed electrons have non-vanishing weak charge. Right-handed electrons, on the other hand, don't interact with weak bosons. It can be seen even from the equation above, since chirality is conserved and anti-neutrinos are always right-handed.